# NestJS + GraphQL: How to avoid circular dependencies in resolvers

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs

Let's say i have two entities:

```js
// user.entity.ts

@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class User {
  @Field()
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Field()
  @Column({ unique: true })
  username: string;

  @Column({ select: false })
  password: string;

  @Field(() => [Task])
  @OneToMany(() => Task, (task) => task.author)
  authorOfTasks: Task[]
}
```

and

```js
// task.entity.ts

@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Task {
  @Field()
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  title: string;

  @Field()
  @Column({ nullable: true })
  description?: string;

  @Field(() => User)
  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.authorOfTasks)
  author: User;
}
```

So in resolvers i need to resolve `authorOfTasks` field in `UserResolver` and `author` field in `TaskResolver`. To do this i need to inject `UserService` and `TaskService` in both `UserResolver` and `TaskResolver`. Like this:

```js
// user.resolver.ts

@Resolver(of => User)  
export class UserResolver {  
  constructor(  
    private userService: UserService,  
    private taskService: TaskService  
  ) {}  

    // here are some queries that using userService
  
  @ResolveField(() => [Task])  
  async authorOfTasks(  
    @Parent() author: User  
  ) {  
    return this.taskService.getTasksByAuthor(author)  
  }  
}
```

and

```js
// task.resolver.ts

@Resolver()  
export class TaskResolver {  
  constructor(  
    private taskService: TaskService,  
    private userService: UserService  
  ) {}  
    
  // here are some queries that using taskService  
  
  @ResolveField(() => User)  
  async author(  
    @Parent() task: Task  
  ) {  
    return this.userService.getUserById(task.author.id)  
  }  
}
```

As you can see there are `TaskService` and `UserService` injected in both those resolvers and it ends up with Nest complaining about circular dependencies in my app and suggesting me to use `forwardRef` to inject those dependencies. Ofcourse i can use that technique, but Nest documentation itself tells me that i should avoid circular dependencies when possible.

So my question is - what to do in this situation? Maybe i should reorganize my app somehow? How then? I want to keep my code modular as much as i can. My current structure looks like this:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Circular references are quite common in GraphQL and perfectly fine - a parent object refers to an array of children and the child refers to the parent(s). This is a nest detail.

Comment: So basically i just need to omit Nest's suggestion of avoiding circular deps and go for forwardRef method?

Comment: Doesn't this circular dependency crash your tests? I receive the following error ` Cannot find module '@/user/entities' from 'tasks/entities/tasks.entity.ts'` when importing `import { User } from '@/user/entities';` and having the following property: `@ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.casinoTokens)
  user: User;`

Comment: Vitomir, i have not set up tests yet. It seems for me that this is path resolving problem, that is not related to my question. Probably you need to configure paths in `tsconfig.json` and/or `jest.config.ts`

Answer (score 0):

While I do agree with [@michel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2805154/michel-floyd) 's answer that circular dependencies are fairly common in GraphQL, I strongly disagree with the notion that one can "disable NestJS" warning for it.

The proper way for it would be to use `forwardRef()` as mentioned in NestJS doc [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency#moduleref-class-alternative). I too had a circular dependency problem when using NestJS and GraphQL and I resolved it at the Module level instead of Service level.

Comment: how did you resolve it at the Module level instead of Service level?

Comment: By using `forwardRef()` instead.